# Use SQL to Filter Drupal Views

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-views, cck, drupal-exposed-filter

I have a content type with a CCK integer field which takes a unix timestamp. I would like to create a view with a filter that takes the MySQL function "UNIX_TIMESTAMP":

[image: screenshot]

If there is no way of doing this, how can I alter the SQL generated for the view?

Comment: You really ought to be using a date field, then you'd have "Now" in all of your filter options. If Views and CCK know your field is a date, they give you a lot more flexibility in how they filter and display the field.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution which involves implementing the views_pre_execute hook inside the views module.

I've documented it [here](http://drupal.org/node/409808#comment-1492672) in the comment labeled "Use SQL value for filter value on CCK integer field".

I'm not very happy with this solution, though, because it seems a bit of a hack.

Comment: Sidenote: The comment 'label' is actually a link to the comment itself, so you can link directly to it: http://drupal.org/node/409808#comment-1492672